# After Effects: How to launch an external process and detach it

Tags: python, cmd, jsx, after-effects

I've got an After Effects Scripting question, but I'm not sure it will be resolved with AE knowledge, maybe more with standalone development.

I want to launch an external process from After Effects, actually I want to launch a render of the openned AEP file with the aerender.exe provided with After Effects while keeping it usable.

```
var projectFile = app.project.file;
var aeRender = "C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe After Effects CC 2018\\Support Files\\aerender.exe";
var myCommand = "-project" + " " + projectFile.fsName;
system.callSystem("cmd /c \""+aeRender+"\"" + " " + myCommand);
```

So I wrote this simple JSX code and it works, it renders the scene render queue properly.
But After Effects is freezing, it waits for the end of the process.
I want it to stay usable.

So I tried to write a .cmd file and launch it with AE system.callSystem and I got the same problem,
I tried to go through an .exe file (compiled from a simple python with pyInstaller), same problem :

```
import sys
import subprocess

arg = sys.argv
pythonadress = arg[0]
aeRender = arg[1]
projectFileFSname = arg[2]

myCommand = "-project" + " " +projectFileFSname
callSystem = "cmd /c \""+aeRender +"\"" + " " + myCommand
subprocess.run(callSystem)
```

I even tried with "cmd /c start ", and it seems to be worse as After Effects continue freezing after the process is completed.

Is there a way to make AE believe the process is complete while it's actually not ?

Any help would be very apreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`system.callSystem()` will freeze the script's execution so instead, you can dynamically create a .bat file and run it with `.execute()`.

Here's a sample .js:

```
var path = {
  "join": function ()
  {
    if (arguments.length === 0) return null;

    var args = [];

    for (var i = 0, iLen = arguments.length; i < iLen; i++)
    {
      args.push(arguments[i]);
    }

    return args.join(String($.os.toLowerCase().indexOf('win') > -1 ? '\\' : '/'));
  }
};

if (app.project.file !== null && app.project.renderQueue.numItems > 0)
{
  var
  // aeRenderPath = path.join(new File($._ADBE_LIBS_CORE.getHostAppPathViaBridgeTalk()).parent.fsName, 'aerender.exe'), // works only in CC 2018 and earlier
  aeRenderPath = path.join(new File(BridgeTalk.getAppPath(BridgeTalk.appName)).parent.fsName, 'aerender.exe'),
  batFile = new File(path.join(new File($.fileName).parent.fsName, 'render.bat')),
  batFileContent = [
    '"' + aeRenderPath + '"',
    "-project",
    '"' + app.project.file.fsName + '"'
  ];

  batFile.open('w', undefined, undefined);
  batFile.encoding = 'UTF-8';
  batFile.lineFeed = 'Unix';
  batFile.write(batFileContent.join(' '));
  batFile.close();

  // system.callSystem('explorer ' + batFile.fsName);
  batFile.execute();

  $.sleep(1000); // Delay the script so that the .bat file can be executed before it's being deleted
  batFile.remove();
}
```

You can, of course, develop it further and make it OSX compatible, add more features to it .etc, but this is the main idea.

Here's a list with all the aerender options (if you don't already know them): https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/automated-rendering-network-rendering.html

Btw, `$._ADBE_LIBS_CORE.getHostAppPathViaBridgeTalk()` will get you the "AfterFX.exe" file path so you can get the "aerender.exe" path easier this way.

EDIT: `$._ADBE_LIBS_CORE` was removed in CC2019 so you can use `BridgeTalk` directly instead for CC 2019 and above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed answer Alex !
I just accidentally found an other way using `system.callSystem("explorer "+batFile.fsName) `

Comment: Yep, it does the exact thing as `execute()`.

Comment: Actually it seems like with `system.callSystem("explorer " + batFile.fsName)` the rendering process starts way slower..
I'm not really sure why but `execute()` might be a better approach.
I've also edited the javascript sample with a `path.join` implementation of the `path` module found in Node JS, so you can build the path more elegantly.

Comment: Nice precision ! I didn't notice this delay, but renders are often very long, so the process start duration becomes less important.